# C# bowling calculator. Array of classes returning null

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, null

I am working on a project in c# visual studio in which i am attempting to make a bowling calculator. i have made a class for frames which contains a throw1 and throw2. I first fill the array of classes with one button and calculate score after game completion. when i go to calculate score it tells me i have null values.below is my form code the class is just 
 class frames
    {
        public int intThrow1;
        public int intThrow2;
    }

the main form is

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    frames[] frame = new frames[11];

    public Form1()
    {


        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int intFrst = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        int intScnd = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        if (lbxScorecard.Items.Count <= 21)
        {
            int intIndx = 0;
            if (intFrst == 10)
            {
                frame[intIndx] = new frames();
                frame[intIndx].intThrow1 = intFrst;
                frame[intIndx].intThrow2 = 0;
                lbxScorecard.Items.Add(frame[intIndx].intThrow1);
                lbxScorecard.Items.Add(frame[intIndx].intThrow2);
                intIndx += 2;
            }
            else
            {
                frame[intIndx] = new frames();
                frame[intIndx].intThrow1 = intFrst;
                frame[intIndx].intThrow2 = intScnd;
                lbxScorecard.Items.Add(frame[intIndx].intThrow1);
                lbxScorecard.Items.Add(frame[intIndx].intThrow2);
                intIndx++;

            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("max throws");
        }




    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int intScore = 0;

        for (int index = 0; index <= 11; index++)
        {

            if (frame[index].intThrow1 == 10 && index < 9)  // here is where it throws a null exception stating the index may be empty
            {
                if (frame[index + 1].intThrow1 != 10)
                {
                    intScore = intScore + frame[index].intThrow1 + frame[index + 1].intThrow1 + frame[index + 1].intThrow2;
                }
                else if (frame[index].intThrow1 == 10)
                {
                    intScore = intScore + frame[index].intThrow1 + frame[index + 1].intThrow1 + frame[index + 2].intThrow1;
                }
            }
            else if (frame[index].intThrow1 + frame[index].intThrow2 == 10 && index < 9)     //it was throwing the same exception here until i added && index<9 in the if statements.
            {
                intScore = intScore + frame[index].intThrow1 + frame[index].intThrow2 + frame[index + 1].intThrow1;
            }
            else 
            {
                intScore = intScore + frame[index].intThrow1 + frame[index].intThrow2;
            }

        }
        MessageBox.Show(intScore.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is:

```
frames[] frame = new frames[11];
```

You also need to instantiate each element of the array like you did in the `button1_Click` function:

```
frame[intIndx] = new frames();
```

Also note that you have a class variable `frame` and the same one in `button2_Click` which is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I thought the array needed to have a defined limit for a max amount of frames. also wouldnt my loop with an index counter instantiate a new frame[index] each button click?

Comment: Your loop in `button1_Click` will do that. But as I said, because you declare `frame` **again** inside `button2_Click` then you are not using the class variable `frame` that you initizlized inside `button1_Click`.

Comment: oh yeah i forgot to delete that before i posted it i was getting the error before than and thought that would fix it lol then i came here

Comment: update i deleted that line and i still get the error im trying to use the class array in the button 2 event to loop through and calculate the score. do i need to repopulate the array again in the button 2 click or can i use the frame[] from button 1

Comment: You can use the `frame` from button 1 if you **do** call it **before** button 2. Then it is initialized... Without a full [mcve] I can't really see anything wrong with the other code.

Comment: i fill the array first with button1 and whe i click button2 to calculate it give me *An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in bowlingAlgorithm.exe* as if i didnt fill the array or there is null values at `if (frame[index].intThrow1 == 10 && index < 9)`. stating i need to instantiate the object using a 'new' to create the instance

Comment: added comments where i receive errors and program crashes

Comment: Make sure you **always** instantiate all the array of `frames`. You probably have some "gaps" in it... Just make sure it is always created and follow with a debugger, it's not a problem.